# saving postgres query output to multple files

Tags: postgresql, csv

Is there a way to save postgres query output to multiple files.

I am using below query to save the output to a tab-separated file but it is taking really long.

```
psql "host= port= dbname= user= password=" -AF $'\t' --no-align -f splice_site_v1_23mer.sql -o 23mer.tsv
```

Thanks

Comment: what does `splice_site_v1_23mer.sql` do?  If you're using `psql`, couldn't you just process `splice_site_v1_23mer.sql` line-by-line, sending the output to a different file each time?

Comment: There is no reason to think saving to multiple files will make it faster.  But you can use `\o` within the -f file (between queries, not within one) to change the output destination.

Comment: @jjanes could you please explain it bit more (with example query)? Thanks

Comment: @richyen could you please explain how to send output to a different file each time? I am new to Postgres so not aware of it. The SQL query has couple of WITH statements and a select statement to get the final output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a big postgres table into multiple csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187391/split-a-big-postgres-table-into-multiple-csv)