# Split a big postgres table into multiple csv

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-copy

I am using following psql query to connect to a remote host and split a big table into multiple csv files.

```
psql -h xx -p xx -U xx -d xx -c "\COPY (select * from table) TO program 'split --lines 1000' (format csv)
```

I am not getting what mistake I am making here.

Comment: Note: there is a double quote missing at the end of the line.

Comment: While I think Jim Jones answer is cleaner, your command also worked for me once I added the missing double quote at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `STDOUT`?

```
$ psql -d db -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM t) TO STDOUT CSV " | split -1000
```

Comment: Can I give a sql query file as an input here like this. `psql -d db -c "COPY ($(<splice_site_v1_9mer.sql)) TO STDOUT CSV" | split 1000`

Comment: You have to use -f to pass a file, but it already needs to have a COPY command in it

Comment: It worked without -f. But will have a look.. Thanks